# Export Problems - to .apk

Tags: android, package

App works fine when tested from Eclipse on phone via USB/Sync, when I try and Export it to an .apk, the Manifest.xml looses track of 2 activities under the parent "MasterActvity". Then even the USB/Sync stops working because it can't locate the activities. No memory storage is used, just text displays.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.theoreferenceguide"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="14"
    android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.theoreferenceguide.MasterActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name="TipActivity"></activity>  This keeps getting kicked out during .apk
    <activity android:name="UccActivity"></activity>  This keeps getting kicked out during .apk
</application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: Note: had problems with keystore passwords and had to create a new keystore file.

Comment: post maybe your manifest?

Comment: Added the activities in the Manifest several times, keeps kicking them out. Dont' know if it's somehow assocated with the keystore.

Comment: I was suggesting to post your android manifest file here, so that we can check if there is anything wrong there.

Comment: You are missing the package in the `android:name` of your missing activities. Maybe that's the cause? You can use ".TipActivity" to use default package

Comment: Added the ".", and when I exported it, it kicked it out of the Manifest.xml

Comment: What you mean with kicked out? I can't understand

Answer (score 0):

I agree with nicopico.  It looks like you are missing the . infront of the activity which tells the manifest that the activity is in the local namespace.  Alternatively if TipActivity is in the same namespace as MasterActivity you can also do android:name="com.example.theoreferenceguide.TipActivity"

Comment: Ok, I tried it with just "." and with com.example..." and both times it kicks out the 2 activities when producing the .apk file. Frustrated, I removed ALL Eclips, SDK and files and started with a clean slate. New keystore and all, same result. Missing something stupid.